# Q: Defining Markov-Chain Probability Matrix States | Specific Academic Paper

Tags: algorithms, markov-chains, data-sets

I am working on a uni project, for which i will model synthetic electricity consumption time series using Markov-Chains. I am reading through current academic literature on that topic and came across an interesting paper (link below).

The authors use a 24x24 probability matrix for the different states that a household can be in, in terms of energy consumption. This makes sense, as there are 24 hours within a day. I *think* the values of the matrix describe the probability that a certain household is going to move from the current state of a given hour to the mean state of all datasets in the next hour. I am not completely sure on this though. So the unit of the matrix elements should be probably in kWh.

My question is how did they generate the matrix? I am not sure if the next sentence has something to do with it: "*Bin sizes for sampling were chosen based on standard deviation (0.0837) and mean electricity consumption (0.5525kW) for a sample of 4,500 Irish dwellings*"

The filled out 24x24 Matrix is not given in the paper, only the final results of the model.

If you want to take a look within the paper, ctrl+f this phrase: "*Markov chain model using a 24x24 probability*" and it should lead you to the part of the paper on page 5.

Citation:
Duffy, Aidan & McLoughlin, Fintan & Conlon, Michael. (2010). The Generation of Domestic Electricity Load Profiles through Markov Chain Modelling.

[link to the paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254584463_The_Generation_of_Domestic_Electricity_Load_Profiles_through_Markov_Chain_Modelling)

[direct pdf download](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aidan-Duffy/publication/254584463_The_Generation_of_Domestic_Electricity_Load_Profiles_through_Markov_Chain_Modelling/links/542913090cf2e4ce940c69aa/The-Generation-of-Domestic-Electricity-Load-Profiles-through-Markov-Chain-Modelling.pdf)

Comment: Hi! Yes, sorry, i have been editing this post a bit much. I will restructure it and finish with a question

Comment: Again, thanks for the headsup. I hope everything is clear now. Please let me know if there still is confusion

Answer (score 0):

I find the paper unclear: it just doesn't seem to explain very clearly where they got the Markov chain from or what the meaning of states or transitions are.  I find their explanation of the Markov chain (the paragraphs where they explain their model) confusing and unclear.  The only recourse I can see is to contact the authors to ask them for more information.

Comment: Right, I have messaged the authors on their TU Dublin mails. One mail seems to be inactive - I suspect this was the main author who finished his PhD almost a decade ago. I tried to reach out to him via other public portals. Maybe he or the co-authors will reply next year. I will make sure to update this post then.

Do you have an idea how you would generate this probability matrix, based on a given dataset?

Comment: @Stefan44, I have no clue what they did.  If I were going to try to create a Markov chain, I'd ignore what they did and try to come up with something that I thought was sensible, based on my own understanding of the application domain (electricity consumption) and on the dataset.  In this case I don't understand that topic and don't have access to such a dataset so I would not be able to give a very good suggestion.